# How can I get an Xml attribute with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have the following XML:

```
<Openings width="20" height="10" layers="1">
  <opening>
    <item>
      <x>1.5</x>
      <y>2.25</y>
      <width>3.5</width>
      <height>5.5</height>
      <type>rectangle</type>
    </item>
  </opening>
</Openings>
```

I have the following javascript code:

```
$(openings).each(function(j, opening_el)
{
  console.log("layers: " + $(opening_el).attr("layers")); //This is not working
});
```

I would like it to print out "layers: 1";

Comment: The code should work if `openings` has a correct selector...you have another problem. Show more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this [help](http://jsfiddle.net/5J852/28/)

```
$("Openings").attr("layers")
```

Please let me know if this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have incorrect selector for targetting the dom with tag opening. it should be `$('Openings')`. You also need to use `$(this)` to access current dom in `.each()` loop.

Try this:

```
 $('Openings').each(function(){
     console.log("layers: " + $(this).prop("layers")); 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing quotes while calling jQuery on `openings` tag and use `this` to get current instance of html element in loop.

```
$('Openings').each(function(j, opening_el)
{
  console.log("layers: " + $(this).attr("layers"));
});
```

Working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NLT8p/228/)

Comment: capitalization should not matter

Comment: @epascarello, you are right. corrected in answer. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are missing the quotes as has been said. This version should work fine.

```
$('openings').each(function(j, opening_el)
{
  console.log("layers: " + $(opening_el).attr("layers")); //This is working
});
```